# 3NF Database tables

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, 3nf, third-normal-form

I am a bit confused about this **3NF (third normal form)** thing. I have a project which I need to do and it needs to be in **3NF**. I have created some tables which describes different parts of a computer.

For example I have a table called `CPU` and a table called `COMPUTERSYSTEM`. The `CPU` got the columns `NAME`, `PRICE`, `SOCKETTYPE` and `CLOCKSPEED`. The `COMPUTERSYSTEM` table is a combination of different components, which are in the `CPU` table or some other component table like `GPU`.

So my question is, is this **3NF**? is the table `CPU` **3NF**? I understand **3NF** as every row needs to be dependent on the `primary key`, and my `primary key` is the name in all tables, isn't Price and clockspeed etc. dependent on name?

Comment: "I understand 3NF as every row needs to be dependent on the primary key" That is not a definition of 3NF, so you don't seem to understand it. Instead of calling 3NF a "thing", suggest you find & quote & try to apply a definition. You are not even supplying relevant info to answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

3NF, or Third Normal Form refers to the organization of a table that follows the first 3 of 5 rules of normalization:

- 1NF = No repeating groups (Phone1, Phone2, etc)
- 2NF = 1NF + all non-key attributes directly related to PK
- 3NF = 2NF + all attributes directly related to PK (FK to 2NF tables
  included)

SOCKET
SocketTypeId
SocektTypeDescription

CPU
CpuId
Manufacturer
SocketTypeId (FK to Socket)
ClockSpeed
Price

COMPUTER
ComputerSystemId
ComputerSystemName
CpuId (FK to CPU)
etc...

SOCKET is 2NF because it has no repeating groups and it's only non-key column (SocketTypeDescription) is directly related to its primary key (SocketTypeId)

CPU is 3NF because it has no repeating groups, all it's non-key columns are directly related to its primary key and its reference to an external table is directly related to its primary key as well.

COMPUTER is also 3NF for the same reasons.